# Как сделать прогрузку страниц в webbrowser?

Tags: c#

На форме есть компонент webbrowser и кнопка "далее", так же есть текстовый файл с перечнем ссылок, которые должны открываться при каждом нажатии на кнопку "далее". т.е. произошло нажатие - отркылась первая ссылка, ещё раз нажали - вторая ссылка и т.д.. как это организовать?

заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

1. После инициализации загрузить строки в массив:

   ```
   string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
   ```
2. Конвертить массив в стек:

   ```
   stack = new Stack<string>(readText);
   ```
3. В обработчике кнопки:

   ```
   this.webBrowser1.Navigate(stack.Pop());//Удаляет и возвращает объект из верхней части Stack<T>.
   ```